# Color Animation With jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make a game, and when the HP bar slides down, the color's supposed to change from green to yellow to orange to red. But when I just make the code change from green to red, the HP bar turns to brown and *then* fades to red. How can I change it to fit my needs? I've tried adding these `{backgroundColor: "yellow"} {backgroundColor: "orange"}`, but it doesn't work. You can check it out here: http://jsbin.com/duwozi/1/edit?html, output

---

HTML

```
<div id="hp_wrapper">
  <div id="hp_bar">HP</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
  $("#hp_bar").animate({width: "0px", backgroundColor: "red"}, 10000);
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [CSS3 animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) instead.

In doing so, you can specifiy multiple steps with different colors.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsbin.com/comolenidi/1/edit?html,output)

```
#hp_bar {
  -webkit-animation: 10s colorFade forwards;
  animation: 10s colorFade forwards;
}
@keyframes colorFade {
  0% { background-color: green;}
  33% { background-color: yellow; }
  66% { background-color: orange; }
  100% { background-color: red; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes colorFade {
  0% { background-color: green;}
  33% { background-color: yellow; }
  66% { background-color: orange; }
  100% { background-color: red; }
}
```

Just add additional vendor prefixes for [additional browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation).

---

If you want the animation to occur at a certain time, you could add the animation properties to a selector like `#hp_bar.animate`:

[**Example Here**](http://jsbin.com/novebeyisu/1/edit?html,output)

```
#hp_bar.animate {
  -webkit-animation: 10s colorFade forwards;
  animation: 10s colorFade forwards;
}
```

Then you would add the `animate` class to the element whenever the animation should occur:

```
$("#hp_bar").addClass('animate').animate({width: "0px"}, 10000);
```

Comment: What does @keyframes stand for?

Comment: How can I make the HP bar longer (200 px) again? I tried `.css("width", "200px")` and `.addClass("health_potion")`. Neither works.                              `.health_potion {                                                                                                                    width: 200px;                                                                                                }`

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS3 animations [as Josh Crozier suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28710331/color-animation-with-jquery-ui/28710412#28710412) is probably the way to go, but if you still wanted to use jQuery UI, you could use discrete animations and chain the animation calls to force an intermediate color (but note that doing it this way causes a pause in the middle because it's not a uniform deceleration over the entire interval as it is with one animation):

```
$("#hp_bar").animate({
    width: "50%",
    backgroundColor: "yellow"
  }, 5000).animate({
    width: "0px",
    backgroundColor: "red"
  }, 5000);
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
  $("#hp_bar").animate({
    width: "50%",
    backgroundColor: "yellow"
  }, 5000).animate({
    width: "0px",
    backgroundColor: "red"
  }, 5000);
});
```

```css
#game_wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  /* margin-left: 480px; */
}
#hp_bar {
  height: 24px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #00CC00;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
#hp_wrapper {
  height: 24px;
  width: 540px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-top: -8px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#hp_scale {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: light;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: -3px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="game_wrapper">
    <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#inv_tab">One</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#map_tab">Two</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#save_tab">Three</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p id="hp_scale">0....5....10....15....20....25.....30.........40.........50.........60.........70.........80.........90.........100</p>
          <div id="hp_wrapper">
            <div id="hp_bar">HP</div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div id="inv_tab">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
      </div>
      <div id="map_tab">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
      </div>
      <div id="save_tab">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 1+ I didn't realize you could chain animations like that.. nice.